# PyQgis How could I open the "identify results" dock using "onSelectionChange()"

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, vector-layer

Using `iface.mapCanvas().selectionChanged.connect(function)` I'd like to open the Identify result dock for the selected feature as shown below:

[image]

it could be manually done by selecting the feature with the identify tool, but how is it done connecting the selection signal to it?